# Streaming not possible in internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-11

I have an application that broadcast my screen over the network. in other browser it is working correctly but in internet explorer its not working and always shows to download a file instant of playing streaming.

in other browser like chrome

[image]

but in internet explorer its not working ....

[image]

i have installed many plugin like quick time active x, java etc.

Comment: what format is the file being downloaded? what format is the video file?

Comment: it is the broadcast of screen. commonly these are multiple frames of image that refresh through socket connection.

Comment: ...huh. share your code, still not clear exactly what your working with, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is difficult to answer without knowing the media type of the streaming.
But I would suggest try installing VLC or the latest media player with updated codecs. Also try disabling any download manager that you might be having.

Note: You can also try the streaming option of VLC as it has a VLC server as well.

Hope that helps.

Also suggested: Buy an authenticated version of Windows or Activate your copy of Windows :P

Comment: in vlc it plays good. i am trying to run on internet explorer.

Comment: Then I guess you will have to change your streaming strategy or share it here because without any code to look at,its very difficult to guess the cause of the problem.

Comment: the problem with internet explorer. i have solved the issue...... thanks for your response.

Comment: You are welcome. It would be great if you could also share how you solved it.